# Swapping each letter in a string sequentially using R

Tags: r, string

For those fellow DnD fans, I recently found the Ring of the Grammarian. Thus I am trying to make a quick script for generating a list of sensible words based on swapping letters from an input string. For example, I want to input "mage hand" and have the program return a list or dataframe which reads;

```
cage hand
...yada yada ...
mage band
mage land
...yada yada ...
mage bang
```

so far, I've only gotten as far as this:

```
dictionary<-data.frame(DICTIONARY)
spell.suggester<-function(x){
  for (i in 1:nchar(x)) {
    for (k in 1:length(letters)) {
      res1<-gsub(pattern = x[i] ,replace = letters[k], x)
  res2<-grep("\\bres1\\b",dictionary[,1],value = F)
  if_else(res2>1,print(grep("\\bres1\\b",dictionary[,1],value = T)),"nonsense")
  return()
    }
  }
}
spell.suggester(x = "mage hand")
```

but I end up with an error message which reads

```
character(0) 
NULL
```

I haven't found any answers on stack using R. Could someone please help me with some suggestions and guidance?

Comment: It seems that you need three arguments in gsub, this works for me: `gsub(pattern = "a", x =  "b",  replacement = "c")`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this typo out, I will make an adjustment to my question

Comment: "\\bres1\\b" here you probably were trying to construct a string using `res1`. Have a look at `paste0` function for that. Also see `glue` package for string template s.

Answer (score -1):

Your major problem here is that you're trying to index each letter of a string, and R doesn't like letting you do that - it treats a string as a whole value, so attempting to index the letters fails.

To fix that, you can use `strsplit` to turn a string into a vector of individual characters that you can index as normal.

Your second issue the dictionary search seems a bit over-complicated; you can use `%in%` to check if a value is present in a vector.

The code below shows a minimal example of how to do this; it only works with single words, and relies on you having a decent dictionary to check valid words against.

```
# minimal example of valid word list
dictionary <- c("vane", "sane", "pane", "cane",
                "bone", "bans", "bate", "bale")

spell.suggester<-function(spell){

  #Split spell into a vector of single characters
  spell_letters <- strsplit(spell,"")[[1]]

  # Once for each letter in spell
  for (i in 1:nchar(spell)) {

    # Once for each letter in letters
    for (k in 1:length(letters)) {

      #If the letter isn't a space
      if (spell_letters[i] != " "){

        # Create a new word by changing one letter
        word <-gsub(pattern = spell_letters[i] ,replace = letters[k], spell)

        # If the word is in the list of valid words
        if (word %in% dictionary){

          # print the possibility
          print(word)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

spell.suggester(spell="bane")
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this typo out, I will make an adjustment to my question